# Laravel 5.2 - Auth::login not preserve when using new \App\User

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I've used these code to **authenticate username from external source without using database**, but laravel 5.2 not save the authentication, and request the external source every time.

```
class Authenticate
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
        {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
                } else {
                    $username = getFromExternalSource();
                    if($username==null){ redirect()->guest('auth/login'); }
                    $user = new \App\User(['username'=>'admin']);
                    Auth::login($user);
                }
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
}
```

But when I change Auth::login using $user model get from database it work, I don't know why:

```
$userDB = \App\User::where('username','=','admin')->first();
Auth::login($userDB);
```

My route (for example I want to access http://myApp/api)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('api/', 'ApiController@index');
    });
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['csrf']], function () {
       Route::controllers([
           'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
           'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
       ]);
   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know for default authenticate method, you need to pass model that exists in database. In your example you created just object and assigned to it `username` property.

If you need to authenticate selected user, you should use:

```
Auth::loginUsingId($id);
```

(where in place of `$id` you should pass id of user you want to authenticate - in your case id of user with username `admin`)

Comment: Thanks. I've just clarified my question, but I want to authenticate & authorize using external source(like OpenAM) but I don't want to store these identification to App database.

Comment: Ok, have you changed default `auth.php` ?

Comment: @o0omycomputero0o Have you tried changing `$user = new \App\User(['username'=>'admin']);` into `$user = new \App\User(['username'=>'admin', 'id' => 'admin']);`

Comment: I've tried this solution too but it didn't worked. In anyway, it've just worked for the current request.